# Python calculation doesn't match instructor's expected output

Tags: python

I have an assignment for school (we mainly use Python) which requires me to make a program with the following variables: `c1, c2, c3, average, reward`. The variables that start with `c` are scores (0/10, type is `float`). The variable `average` is the average score of the three `c`-scores. The variable `reward` contains a reward which is 25 cents for each point in the average score. If I have an average score of 7.4 for example, I'd have a reward of `reward = average * 25`.

The `c` variables have the following values:

```
c1 = 5.6
c2 = 7.3
c3 = 8.4
```

The output of the assignment should be:

```
These are my scores: c1 = 5.6 and c2 = 7.3 and c3 = 8.4
My average score: 7.100000000000005
My reward: 532 Cents
```

Instead, my code outputs this:

```
These are my scores: c1 = 5.6 and c2 = 7.3 and c3 = 8.4
My average score: 7.099999999999999
My reward: 177 Cents
```

This is my code right now:

```
#The required variables
#My scores
c1 = 5.6
c2 = 7.3
c3 = 8.4

#Variables calculating the needed info using the c-variables above
#My average score
average = (c1 + c2 + c3) / 3
#My reward
reward = int(average * 25)

#Output the info as required by the assignment
print("These are my scores: c1 = " + str(c1) + " and c2 = " + str(c2) + " and c3 = " + str(c3))
print("My average score: " + str(average))
print("My reward: " + str(reward) + " Cents")
```

I've been trying to figure this out, but I just can't see the issue. The information that's being showed is mathematically correct. It could be that my teacher made a mistake, but it could also be my mistake. Can you see what I'm doing wrong that causes the program to output (possibly) incorrect info?

Comment: 7,1 x 25 cannot be equal to 532

Comment: Are you sure reward isn't supposed to be `$0.75`? That's what the expected output assumes. As far as the average, that just looks like floating point errors to me.

Comment: So you think the values in the question are just incorrect?

Comment: @AdamSmith Nope, just checked it out, it's 25.

Comment: The expected output uses $0.75 instead. If it's wrong, I can't help you with that :-P. The actual average is `7.1`. You can get that exact number in Python by using `decimal.Decimal` objects instead of floats. Regardless, it looks like there's no answerable problem in your code so I'm voting to close.

Comment: @AdamSmith Okay thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that the reward is supposed to be 25 cents for each point in the *total* score rather than the *average* score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An average of 7.1 times 25 would never return a reward of 532 instead it returns 177.5 which is what you get in your output. It's not an error in the code. You should check the value for reward points.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `round` function to round the float to have only one decimal digit.

```
print("My average score: " + str(round(average,1)))
```

outputs

```
My average score: 7.1
```